# Mobile Web: Detecting when images have been disabled

Tags: html, image, mobile

I've run into a very annoying problem for mobile web. The website I have uses images for most of it's buttons, both `<a href="..."><img>` and `<input type='image'>`. Consequently, if the user disables images, the website not only does not look good, but they also lose all ability to navigate the site. In particular, Android does not display `alt` information on images, so there is quite effectively nothing to hint at images not displaying.

Is there some way to determine if a browser has disabled images without using JavaScript? I'd like to display a more generic text optimized site if they have disabled it.

Comment: I'm amazed android does not process the alt property of images when they're disabled.

Comment: I've done some research, I believe it is a webkit issue that has existed since 2005. Quite sad really.

Comment: If you have images disabled, it's probably removing background images as well, right? I was going to suggest using the images as background images, but I wasn't sure if that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any JavaScript at all? I am afraid it is not possible, at least on the client side.

In HTML there are NOFRAME and NOSCRIPT tags, but no equivalent tag for images, whose contents would be displayed only if images were disabled or not supported.

Then for your A tags wrapping an image, maybe you could make the A tag, instead of its image, responsible for showing the tooltip and for handling events.

Also, to ensure that your layout will not break if the images do not load, you could give the A tag the normal height and width of its image. The same thing would also work for the `<input type='image'>` tags by wrapping them in a span tag and giving it correct attribute values.

For example:

```
<a href="..." style="height: 25px"; width: 80px;" title="Some tooltip text">
    <img...>
</a>

<span onclick="some action" style="height: 30px"; width: 70px;" title="Some other tooltip text">
    <input type='image'...>
</span>
```

Comment: Defining the size of the anchor tag works perfectly. But the input will still require JavaScript. One solution I thought of would unfortunately limit images to people who JavaScript enabled, and that would be to load standard text, and use a JavaScript onload to swap the text out for an image if the image loads. In the end I think setting the anchor size and avoiding the image input type is the best solution.